# Issue with BindDevice function in IBidiSpl

Tags: c#, windows, printers

I am trying to work with bidirectional communication with a printer, but facing some issues with the `BindDevice` function. You can see the image below for more detail.

```cs
public void BindDevice(string printerName) {
    try {
        BidiSpl bidi = (BidiSpl) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(BidiSpl), true);
        _iBidiSpl = (IBidiSpl) bidi;
        //_iBidiSpl.BindDevice(printerName, 0);

        _iBidiSpl.BindDevice(printerName, BIDI_ACCESS_USER);
    }
    catch (SystemException e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Image with immediate window values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your printerName is null. It needs to be then name of a valid printer.

Comment: Please don't use one liners while answering. This best suits in comments only.